# OneNote - associate custom tags with file

Tags: tags, onenote

I am using SharePoint and OneNote. I open the same OneNote file on several computers and others also use the same OneNote file.

I customized the tags on one machine for the OneNote file, but the customizations don't transfer with the file (I have to customize the tags on every machine). Is there a way to have the custom tags be associated with the OneNote file?

For example, I want Ctl-1 to set the "Priority 1" tag no matter where I open the file, and I want that to work for others, also.

Comment: The answer below is good, but this is off topic for SO as a non-developer question.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no way to associate the tags with a file, but you can copy your customizations across machines.

The `preferences.dat` file contains these customizations.

You can find this file at:

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\OneNote\[version]
```

Just copy it to the same location on your other machines.

(This information is based off of this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920254. However, the folder locations referenced in this article are slightly different since it was written for OneNote 2003)

Comment: At some point in the five years since @msft-snovick posted this, this method has stopped working. There is a way, however, you can copy your custom tags. I found a working set of instructions here: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows/suggestions/5681685-win-sync-custom-tags-across-all-devices?page=1&per_page=20 Scroll down to the post titled *"OneNote 2016 Syncronize custom tags"* on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

When copying preferences.dat isn't an option, right-click the custom tag's icon (not the paragraph) in the "other" notebook and choose Add To My Tags.[OneNote 2010 screen shot showing right-click of icon to access Add To My Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/563hh.png)